# Migrate source code from Surround SCM to TFS with History

Tags: tfs

Is there any way to migrate a surround SCM repository to TFS with all it's history like versions, branches and Comments? Now the source is on surround SCM and I want to migrate that TFS repository.

Comment: What kind of solution are you looking for? There isn't a direct export > import functionality. However, both Surround SCM and TFS have APIs that would allow you to translate the history. You would have to write your own and "replay" the operations in order to get your history.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find any existing tool to migrate from Surround SCM to TFS. As @debugthings mentioned in comment, you would have to achieve your goal with APIs.

There is a TFS Integration Tool which is not maintained any more, but you can take it as a reference to implement your solution:

https://tfsintegration.codeplex.com/